# Can we combine SharePoint results and people results in one result source in SharePoint Search 2013?

Tags: 2013

I am able to create a result source with people results and other BCS content using {?{searchTerms} ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople OR ContentSource:BCSSource} but not SharePoint results. I had to explicitly include urls Path:{siteURL} in the query text to search.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.